# Rich text box having { } getting converted into its ANSI value

Tags: development, sharepoint-server

I have a list in which one column is of type Rich text box. 
I am using a console application which reads this list's item and replace a substring
for example RichTextColumn contains value [subtext] then

```
string mytext=item["RichTextColumn"].toString();
mytext=mytext.Replace("[subtext]","******");
```

The above code work fine , but when Rich Text column has **{** or **}** then the code fails
for example if RichTextColumn contains value {subtext} then below can't find it

```
mytext=mytext.Replace("{subtext}","--------");
```

On debugging I found mytext contains **ANSI code for curly braces(&#123)** instead of **{**

Please help me out me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint stores some of the Rich Text characters in ANSI format

[image]

You can decode the string before applying the `Replace` function as below

```
mytext = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(mytext);
mytext=mytext.Replace("{subtext}","--------");
```

Comment: Do you have a source for that image of the table? If so, please share it in your post

Comment: @RobertLindgren I have added the link to image.

Comment: Great, thanks! It's allways nice to give credit to creators